# Emacs24 , org-mode, can't find `latex'(needed to convert LaTeX fragments fo images)

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I want to use the command `C-c C-x C-l` to preview latex code in org-mode.  Since the emacs-nox cannot do this, I tried `apt-get install emacs24`.  However, after I have installed the emacs24 with GUI, I get an error like

```
can't find \`latex'(needed to convert LaTeX fragments to images)
```

I have installed texlive2016, and I can `latex *.tex` in shell command.

I added the `/paht/to/latex` to .emacs, but it don't work well.

Comment: How did you add the /path/to/latex to emacs?

Comment: emacs `C-x C-f ` open ~/.emacs, add ` (setenv "PATH"
  (concat
   ":/path/to/latex"
   (getenv "PATH")
  )
)`

Comment: Can you set `debug-on-error` to `t`, try the preview and post the backtrace somewhere? Also post your org-mode version (`M-x org-version` will tell you). BTW, this is probably better done on the org-mode mailing list.

Comment: Emacs also has `exec-path`, which is initialized to `$PATH` but is distinct.  `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/path/to/latex")`

Answer (score 4):

Adding the following to my `init.el` makes it work:

```
;; Making emacs find latex (so that C-c C-x C-l works on orgmode)
(setenv "PATH" (concat ":/Library/TeX/texbin/" (getenv "PATH")))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/Library/TeX/texbin/")
```

It is not a very pretty solution, but it does the job and is very easy to modify and understand.

This solution worked on a Mac running macOS Sierra and Emacs v25.1.

Answer (score 3):

My crystal ball tells me that the problem is that you're not starting the GUI Emacs from a terminal, so it can't inherit your $PATH settings.  See for example https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10722/ (that question is within OSX, but the same problem appears in other systems).

Apparently you can set env-vars globally (so that they affect all applications, including those started directly from the GUI) in `~/.pam_environment` (that's for GNU/Linux systems).  Note that this is only consulted when you login, so you need to logout+login for changes to take effect.

Comment: thx. I indeed start my GUI Emacs from the super key. But the $PATH in ~/.emacs is working. In fact, my problem is that I  add the /path/to/latex to $PATH, but not also $exec-path, [The difference between exec-path and PATH](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath),

Comment: You shouldn't need to meddle with `$PATH` (nor `exec-path`) in your `~/.emacs` since it should be the same as the `$PATH` used in all other applications: it should be a global setting.

Comment: But when i do this, it is usefull and solve my problem